# Delete element from a static array

Tags: arrays, delphi, pascal

I am trying to remove an item from an array.
The array is not dynamic!

I found many examples on how to do it for the dynamic variant but none for the static.

example from delphi:

```
var
  A: array of integer;
begin
  ...
  A:=[1,2,3,4];
  Delete(A,1,2); //A will become [1,4]
  ...
end;
```

example from another site:

```
type
  TIntArray = array of Integer;
procedure DeleteArrayElement(var AArray: TIntArray; const AIndex: Integer);
begin
  Move(AArray[AIndex + 1], AArray[AIndex], SizeOf(AArray[0]) * (Length(AArray) - AIndex - 1)); 
  SetLength(AArray, Length(AArray) - 1);
end;
...
//call via
DeleteArrayElement(IntArray, 3);
...
```

My array is defined as 0 .. 11 so this is not dynamic(i guess)?

When I try to use the **SetLength** function it says incompatible types.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: don't use an array if you want to remove the elements: use a TList<Integer> if available

Comment: You cannot delete/remove an element from static array. That's what static means: the number of elements is fixed. You can only change or reorder the values.

Comment: Static arrays are, well, static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you declare a static array you tell the compiler that the memory for the whole array should be allocated and retained until the program is terminated (if allocated in global space).

You cannot change the size of a static array. This is the purpose why dynamic arrays are there in Delphi.

The Embarcadero documentation for static arrays says:

> If you create a static array but don't assign values to all its
>   elements, the unused elements are still allocated and contain random
>   data; they are like uninitialized variables.

Comment: Is it possible lets say to take the last item from array and fill it with 0 , add another check in some functions if the array is filled with 0 to not show it?

Comment: Fill last item with zero -> `MyArray[Length(MyArray) - 1] := 0`. Then check in another function for this condition `if MyArray[Length(MyArray) - 1] = 0 then`

Comment: Please see the comment of  @fantaghirocco. Please take his advice. This is the proper and novel way of doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Static arrays don't necessarily persist for the application lifetime unless they are declared as global variables.  As local variables they live on the stack and fall out of scope when the method returns.  As fields of objects or records their lifetime is dictated by the lifetime of their parent object.

Comment: @J - Yes. I assumed in my answer that we all know local variables stay in stack and are pushed and pulled around all the time. But I anyway updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @CharlieH: Instead of _Length(MyArray)-1_ use _HIGH(MyArray)_ - this will also allow you to have _ARRAY[7..9]_ and still access the last entry, whereas Length will give you an index error...

Comment: @vpe27339 re filling last item(s) with zero you could also use a 'count' parameter to tell you how many are current (and not worry about content...)