# How fill with zeros all data of a determinated index in static array of a data struct?

Tags: arrays, delphi, data-structures, delphi-10-seattle

I have the structure below and a `Pointer` to this same structure. 
After it, i have a static array, **`array[0 .. 255] of Client`**. Based in this following complete code, how i can fill a determinated "client" (element) with zeros when "client" (element) "desconnect" or "release space" to a new "client" (element) without lost this fixed size of array (`Clients`)? See my attempt, but i don't know if this idea is right, i belive that no, because IDE says that not is possible assign a `Integer` (0) to `Clients` array.

My attempt was based in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732376/delete-element-from-a-static-array#comment55234009_33732510) where the question is related to static arrays.

```
type
  PClient = ^Client;

  Client = record
    Connections: array [0 .. 1] of TSocket;
    uhId: DWORD;
    _hWnd: HWND;
    Pixels: PByte;
    pixelsWidth, pixelsHeight: DWORD;
    screenWidth, screenHeight: DWORD;
    hDcBmp: HDC;
    minEvent: THandle;
    fullScreen: BOOL;
    windowRect: TRect;
  end;

 var
  Clients: array [0 .. 255] of Client;

//...

function GetClient(Data: Pointer; uhId: Boolean): PClient;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := nil;
  for I := 0 to 255 do
  begin
    if uhId then
    begin
      if Clients[I].uhId = DWORD(Data) then
      begin
        Result := @Clients[I];
        Break;
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      if Clients[I]._hWnd = HWND(Data) then
      begin
        Result := @Clients[I];
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure removeClient;
var
  _client: PClient;
  _uhId: DWORD;
  I: Integer;
begin
  _uhId := 123456;
  _client := GetClient(Pointer(_uhId), True);

  { to add a item i do }

  for I := 0 to 255 do
  begin
    if Clients[I].uhId = 0 then
    begin
      _client := @Clients[I];
    end;
  end;

  { my attempt to fill with 0 (zero) a determinated element and yours propeties }

  for I := 0 to 255 do
  begin
    if Clients[I].uhId <> 0 then
    begin
      Clients[I] := 0; // << Error of "incompatible types"
      _client := @Clients[I];
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You can use `Clients[I] := Default(Client)`. Since the record does not have any managed type, you can also `ZeroMemory(@Clients[I], SizeOf(Client)`.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, thank you, worked fine.

Comment: Be careful when simply Zeroing memory of records especially if they contain reference fields (references to other objects/classes). For instance looking at your code I see that you have a field for midEvent which is of type THandle. Handles often do need to be released properly othervise your applicatin might be leaking handles.

Comment: Any way since you seem to be trying to implement some sort of ClientPool it might not be a bad idea to extend your current record with special finction to reset its fireds to some default state properly doing any additional cleanup when needed. I recomend you check what advanced records are to uderstand better what I mean by exenting your current record